# Water is dropping from car?

Tags: nissan, water-leak

I bought a car yesterday. A 2009 Nissan.

Today, I noticed that water is dripping under the front passenger seat.
Is there anyone who knows what the source of the water might be?

Comment: It may be the air conditioner hose sticking out of the passenger side firewall.  Condensation from the hose could be collecting on the floor.  Or, it may be the evaporator drain port hose got plugged and is overflowing on to the floor.  See this: http://www.nissanclub.com/forums/general-nissan-altima-discussion-1993-2001/251610-water-leak-passenger-side-floor-mat.html

Comment: Is it water or coolant? Coolant is not clear, contains antifreeze and smells slightly sweet. Coolant leaks are serious and yours points to a heater core. Water dripping is condensation or rain intrusion. Not nearly as big a deal!

Comment: What model of Nissan is your car?

Answer (score 3):

The problem more than likely is the drain tube for the A/C unit is plugged. Where this drains from becomes filled up after a bit of use from the A/C and has no place to go, so drains into the passenger side of the cabin. To fix this, you need to find the drain tube. This is usually located on the passenger side of the vehicle by the firewall (usually underneath the A/C condenser box), and can only be seen from underneath. Once you locate the tube (should be rubber-ish), get a long piece of wire (an unbent coat hanger can work wonders here) and stick it up into the tube. You need anywhere from 10" to 24" of wire. When you poke through the blockage you know. Usually there will be a large amount of water come out of the tube and hit you in the face, so don't be surprised.